# Large Number in PHP

Tags: php, largenumber

I have a problem with large number in PHP. My large number will be inserted into the database but everything go wrong.

case 1:

```
$testNumber = "1111111111111111";
$num = $testNumber*1;
echo $num;                           // --> 1.11111111111E+15   (wrong)
echo number_format($num,0,"","");    // --> 1111111111111111    (right)
```

case 2:

```
$testNumber = "11111111111111111";
$num = $testNumber*1;
echo $num;                           // --> 1.11111111111E+16   (wrong)
echo number_format($num,0,"","");    // --> 11111111111111112   (wrong)
```

case 3:

```
$testNumber = "111111111111111111";
$num = $testNumber*1;
echo $num;                           // --> 1.11111111111E+17   (wrong)
echo number_format($num,0,"","");    // --> 111111111111111104  (wrong)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

---

**Thank Wyzard for his suggestion. This is my solution:**

```
$testNumber = "11111111111111111111";
$num = bcmul($testNumber,1);
echo $num;                           // --> 11111111111111111111   (right)
```

and this is very important information:

**"Since PHP 4.0.4, libbcmath is bundled with PHP. You don't need any external libraries for this extension."**

Comment: Where dows `$num` come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those numbers are too large to fit in an [integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php), so PHP treats them as [floats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) instead.  Floating-point numbers have limited precision; they're essentially [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), with a limited number of [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures).  It sounds like you're running into that precision limit.

You may want to use PHP's [BCMath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) extensions for working with numbers that may be very large.

Comment: Thanks Wyzard. Follow your suggestion I found the answer for my question. I will updated to my question above.

Answer (score 1):

For such cases I used the GMP extension (http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php). You start by sending the number as a string to gmp_init (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-init.php), then work using gmp_... functions and then retrieve the result as a string using gmp_strval (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-strval.php)